# java thread object kept alive after run() finishes

Tags: java, multithreading

What could be the reasons for `java.lang.Thread` objects to be kept alive after their `run()` finishes execution? And to help understand this question, how is threads removed from `ThreadGroup` when `run()` is done?

UPDATE: `Thread` objects being kept alive is different from `Thread` being active/alive. I was debugging a `Thread` object leak (rather than `Thread` leak) when I asked this question. For JDKs based on GNU Classpath (Harmony should be one of them, right?), `Thread` is added to `ThreadGroup` in the constructor `Thread.<init>`, and a `Thread` created but not started will be leaked (i.e., kept alive no matter whether `run()` finishes). In HotSpot, `Thread` is added to `ThreadGroup` in `Thread.start()`, which seems to make more sense. In other words, it is added only if it is started, and it is guaranteed to be removed if `run()` doesn't hang. Note that `ThreadGroup` is treated as a GC root.

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking under what circumstances a thread would stay alive when `run()` completes, or under what circumstances the `java.lang.Thread` object would stay around? Your question seems to ask the latter, and the trick there is to remember that, in addition to controlling threads, a `Thread` object is also just a normal ol' Java object, subject to the same GC rules as anyone else. So, even if its thread has long since completed, the `Thread` instance can stick around if some other thread is holding onto it (threads are GC roots).

Trivial example

```
Thread t = new Thread();
t.start(); // will finish almost instantly
t.join();
// ...
```

In this example, the thread finished almost as soon as it started, and certainly by the time that `join()` returned. The `Thread` object, though, survives GC until the `t` reference goes out of scope or is set to another object.

Looking at the code, a Thread is removed from its ThreadGroup via the private method `ThreadGroup.remove(Thread)`, which is invoked by `ThreadGroup.threadTerminated(Thread)`, which is a package-private method invoked by `Thread.exit()`, which is a private method with no invocation in the JDK code; it's presumably invoked by the native thread management code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that some function call in your thread object `run` method has not returned yet and it means actually the run method has not finished yet!

I suggest you that at the very end line of you `run` method print something like "Finished" and then monitor the output in your main program runt time.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that run() finishes because the thread does not show up in the list of active threads in Eclipse debug mode.

Comment: can u send us the code! Otherwise no one can help more than making some guess!

Comment: @ehsun What you mean is 'can you *edit* the code *into your post*'.

Comment: @dacongy So the thread isn't active. So why the question?